# Reading data to compare before updating with .set()

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to keep track of a top score in a firebase database for a simple javascript game. I would like to check if the user's score, a javascript variable, is greater than the current value of 'highscore', a direct child of the database.

In the firebase docs, a value can be returned with something like:

```
var starCountRef = firebase.database().ref('posts/' + postId + '/starCount');
starCountRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  updateStarCount(postElement, snapshot.val());
});
```

The problem with this is the callback is only run when the data is updated, but I want to compare the data before updating it.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Firebase's [transaction()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#transaction) method to achieve this. For example you can do something like:

```
var latestScore = 99;

starCountRef.transaction(function(savedHighScore){
    if(savedHighScore === null || latestScore > savedHighScore){
        return latestScore;  // will update starCountRef with this value
    }else{
        return;  // nothing to update
    }        
});
```

Look at the documentation for a more complete example including error handling.